# Replace part of a line by other part of the same line

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I do have a file like this:

```
<receiver name="anything" type="com.mycompany.plugin.Timer">
  <property name="interval">5000</property>
  <handler name="ReplaceThis" type="com.mycompany.handler.FileBuilderHandler">
    <property name="buildSomething">true</property>
    <handler name="AlsoReplaceThis" type="com.mycompany.handler.FileExporter">
      <property name="overide">true</property>
    </handler>
  </handler>
</receiver>

<receiver name="anything/other" type="com.mycompany.plugin.Timer">
  <property name="intervall">1000</property>
  <handler name="ThisMustBeReplaceAsWell" type="com.mycompany.handler.FileWatcher">
    <property name="interval">2000</property>
    <handler name="ThisMustBeReplaceAsWell" type="com.mycompany.converter.CSConverter">
      <property name="mandant">CE</property>
      <handler name="RemoveThis" type="com.mycompany.handler.FileExporter">
        <property name="outputDir">/usr1/import</property>
      </handler>
    </handler>
```

Now I want all lines with the following beginning

```
 <handler name="
```

to be replace from

```
 <handler name="ReplaceThis" type="com.mycompany.handler.FileBuilderHandler">
```

to someting like this

```
 <handler name="FileBuilderHandler" type="com.mycompany.handler.FileBuilderHandler">
```

So the attribute "name" should have the Classname (last part of the type attribute)

Does anyone has an idea how to solve that with an sed, awk, grep command?

Comment: XML is not regular; using regular expressions to attempt to parse them is the beginning of a descent into madness.  Use a tool designed to faff about with XML (e. g. a DOM parser such at, for instance, `xmlstarlet`) to perform operations such as this.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1421075

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For input structured identical to your sample, this might work:

```
$ sed -E 's/(handler name=")[^"]*"( *type="([^.]*\.)*([^.]*)">)/\1\4"\2/' file
```